# Cross validation with Early Stopping

Tags: cross-validation, scikit-learn, keras

I would like to use EarlyStopping in k-fold cross-validation framework but not to find the optimal number of epochs, but only to reduce overfitting during the trainings runs. 
However, I would like to use a separate validation data set for EarlyStopping and not the test fold during cross validation.
This is exactly where I have a big decision problem. 
Would it be better to separate the validation data from training data before applying cross validation and then use the same validation data for each run. Or would it be better to separate a validation set from the trainings folds before every run so that in every run I have another validation data set for early stopping?

Possibly a naive question, but I'm just unsure about it.

Many thanks

Comment: What's "early stopping"?

Comment: @AdamO EarlyStopping stopps training when a monitored quantity, like accuracy etc., has stopped improving.     Look https://keras.io/callbacks/